# Spring framework, java remoting and user session

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have 3 tomcat servers 
All my applications are deployed as WARs
The first one is  a web server which use remote object by http invoker from server 2
Server 2 is using remote object with http invoker from server 3
I would like to use spring security on server 2 and 3. 
I need to know under which user session the remote method was called
I was thinking on creating a session on each of the servers but I do not know how to do this?
Even if I can replicate the session to all servers how do I tell server 2 that user X called some remote method?

Comment: I am now checking SSO as a solution for this problem. Can anybody tell me if I am on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Well..We use Spring Security on our project. We use 3 Tomcat servers which are under a cluster. We use Sticky session on our LB so that, once the session form between the LB and a Node, the subsequent requests goes to that same node.
I suggest you to put the 3 TOmcat servers under on cluster(its quite easy) and maintain sticky session btw your LB and all nodes.

Comment: I can not use your solution as I have 3 diffrent servers. I can use what you said for each server within the cluster but in my case I need something else. Thanks anyway